# What is the name of the two sections at the left and right of this "classic" Web UI?

Tags: gui-design

This question may sounds weird but I was wondering myslelf if the two sections at the left and the right of an UI had a special name (like header or footer for the top and the bottom parts).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi5Yrz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I think about "banners" but it doesn't sound specific to the left/rigth positioning.
Do you know what's the name of these elements ?

Comment: Left-hand column / Right-hand column?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have always seen those referred to as left or right [sidebars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidebar_%28computing%29), but I don't think there's necessarily a standard name for them like there is for header and footer.

Comment: They were always called sidebars and nowadays you have the <aside> Tag which makes sense

Comment: It's my understanding that the <aside> tag has nothing to do with sidebars- it's more meant to be a side note within an article.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be called as sidebars and still is by some graphic/web designers, but nowadays people calling them more technically as "aside" and I guess that could be due to HTML5... not sure! Hope it helps

Comment: I was going to answer with `<aside />` as well, but an `<aside />` really isn't the same as a sidebar.  An `<aside />` can be *displayed* as a sidebar, but that doesn't mean that it *is* one. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside.